# Loading CSS using Manifest

Tags: javascript, jquery, preload, createjs

How to load CSS with images and audio file using load manifest? 
With or without use of createjs and preload js?
I want to load it first then append it in main? is this possible to do so or not?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the examples in the PreloadJS GitHub - for example the MediaGrid loads all of the supported file types, including CSS, Audio, and images.

http://createjs.com/Demos/PreloadJS/MediaGrid.html
https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/

Note that due to browser limitations, CSS is always added to the DOM immediately. This is because when you are loading using Tags (instead of XHR), it has to be in the DOM to load, and we wanted tag and XHR loading to be consistent.